# How do you make 'xrandr -q' command work in systemd sleep pre script?

Tags: systemd, x11, xrandr, suspend

I want to act depending on which output is active. The script would be placed in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/.

Comment: You want to run an xrandr command inside a hook script? It needs to know what X display to connect to. A quick hack is to just put `DISPLAY=:0` in front of the `xrandr` command like this: `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr -q`. Another option is to just put `export DISPLAY=:0` at the start of the script on its own line. But this is just my guess tho, you didn't provide sufficient information about what is actually not working.